# IntersectionObserver in collision with a play command

Tags: javascript, jquery, intersection-observer

some images on page and one single video
click on image change video `src` and set it to play

```
<img class='aimg' data-v='01.mp4' src='...' alt='img'>
<img class='aimg' data-v='02.mp4' src='...' alt='img'>
<img class='aimg' data-v='02.mp4' src='...' alt='img'>
```

**JS**

```
var vsingle = $('#vsingle');
$('.aimg').on('click', function(){
    let src = $(this).attr('data-v');
    vsingle.attr('src', src);
    vsingle[0].play();
});
```

the above works fine
now I need to pause video if it is not in viewport

```
let io = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if(!entry.isIntersecting){
      entry.target.pause()
    }
  });
});

function modify(el){el.pause();}

$(document).ready(function(){
  io.observe(document.querySelector('#vsingle'));
});
```

this also works, but now there is a problem
when I click on an image - video doesn't play and console says:

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().`

What exactly is in collision here and how to solve ?